# On radio button value change needs to change the list box selected items

Tags: jsf, netbeans

Hi I have list box and radio button group jsf1.1

on change of radio button values needs to change list box selected values
i am setting under radio button ValueChangeEvent,its setting that time but after that its calling some built in class again its changing to previous values.

below is the JSFcode...

```
 <ui:listbox binding="#{weka$DataMining.listbox_pidGroups}" id="listbox_pidGroups"
      items="#{VisualAnalyticsSessionBean.pidStaticInfo.pidGroupsForClusterTree}" label="PID Groups" labelOnTop="true" multiple="true"
      rows="5" selected="#{VisualAnalyticsSessionBean.pidStaticInfo.selectedGroup}"/>
 <h:panelGrid binding="#{weka$DataMining.gridPanel_ClusterType}" id="gridPanel_ClusterType" style="">
     <ui:radioButtonGroup binding="#{weka$DataMining.radioButtonGroup_clusters}" id="radioButtonGroup_clusters"
         items="#{VisualAnalyticsSessionBean.fsdfOptions.clusters}" onClick="common_timeoutSubmitForm(this.form, 'gridPanel_ClusterType')"
         selected="#{VisualAnalyticsSessionBean.fsdfOptions.clusterType}" immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{weka$DataMining.clustergroup_processValueChange}"/>
     <ui:radioButton binding="#{weka$DataMining.radioButton_SingleCluster}" id="radioButton_SingleCluster" label="Single Cluster"
         name="radioButton-group-gridPanel_ClusterType" rendered="false" selected="#{VisualAnalyticsSessionBean.pidParameters.singleCluster}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've `immediate="true"` set on the radio button group component. This means that all other input components which don't have `immediate="true"` set, like as the listbox component, won't set and get their values from the model. Your problem symptoms indicate that you're changing the listbox value by altering the model value. You need to rewrite the value change listener code so that it instead sets the updated value directly on the component. You've bound the listbox component to a `listbox_pidGroups` property of the bean, so you need to call `setValue()` on it instead.

Something like

```
listbox_pidGroups.setValue(newValue);
```